# Make it impossible to save a custom post type with both video and image selected?

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads

I have a custom post type, which creates a slide. I can select if I want to have an image or a video, with two different buttons. If I select both of them it will still save, but the background will show up. How do I make it impossible to save/publish if both an image and a video is selected?

I don't really know what code to provide, as it is code in the post-details.php file + functions.php and the javascript-files.

Is there any easy way to prevent this?

Comment: WordPress' isn't doing this. There's nothing in core WordPress about specifying an image or video for a post type. A plugin or theme you're using is adding this option and you should take it up with the developer.

Comment: I'm modifying a plugin right now, which is not in active development. That's why I'm here trying to figure out things like this!

Comment: Well I don't know how anybody here's supposed to know without the name of the plugin _or_ code. Even then it would be off-topic because it's about 3rd-party software.

Comment: You could solve this by adding a conditional wherever the plugin is adding the actual background and video. Decide which you want to take precedence and then a simple if statement: if a video is set, show it; else if an image is selected, show it; else (insert a fallback if you want one).